# Returning Jobject displays as array of ampty objects in browser

Tags: c#, .net, api

When I do something like this:

```
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetCounties")]
        public JObject Get()
        {
            //Dummy data just for example
            string countiesJson = "{'Everything':[{'county_name':null,'description':null,'feat_class':'Civil','feature_id':'36865',"
                    + "'fips_class':'H1','fips_county_cd':'1','full_county_name':null,'link_title':null,'url':'http://www.alachuacounty.us/','name':'Alachua County'" + ",'primary_latitude':'29.7','primary_longitude':'-82.33','state_abbreviation':'FL','state_name':'Florida'}," +
                    "{'county_name':null,'description':null," + "'feat_class':'Civil','feature_id':'36866','fips_class':'H1','fips_county_cd':'3','full_county_name':null,'link_title':null,'url':'http://www.bakercountyfl.org/','name':'Baker County','primary_latitude':'30.33','primary_longitude':'-82.29','state_abbreviation':'FL','state_name':'Florida'}]}";

            JObject x = JObject.Parse(countiesJson);

            //do some data manipulation here

            return x;
        }
```

I get a response in swagger that looks like this:

[image]

I tried returning it as a Jsonresult but then it adds backslashes everywhere and shows them on swagger as well.

Comment: Why are you return a `JObject` from a Web Api... What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the question. So in the real case. We get data from a different endpoint. Convert it to Jobject and do some manipulatiopn on the data. And then we want to return the Jobject contents as Json